# How should I back up a dual-boot system?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, backup

I am planning to build a new computer in the fall with two hard drives: 1TB for Windows and 500GB for Ubuntu. I also have a 320GB external drive that I am using for backups on my current PC. I want to continue to use this drive for backups of important files. I am not concerned with backups of the operating systems. I am unsure how I should do this backup scheme.

I plan to keep word documents, music, etc. on the Windows drive, while keeping programming stuff on the Ubuntu partition. Is there a way to back up both drives on the same external drive? Or perhaps online in Dropbox? I assume it would be easiest to do it through Ubuntu. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to backup both systems at the same destination disk, I recommend Clonezilla.

Clonezilla allows you to make a mirror of your partitions or entire disk to a destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tar` to pack up the contents of each drive to a separate tarball. You'll need to reinstall the bootloaders after, but that's not particularly difficult if you have the install discs of both. Otherwise you'll need to use `dd` to grab the first few kilobytes of each partition as well as the drive as a whole.